# Deleting a file from a smart device (Windows mobile 6.1) using the Smart Device Connectivity API

Tags: c#, api, windows-mobile, smart-device

I'm using Smart Device Connectivity API to transfer files (with FileDeployer class) to my smart device (Windows mobile 6.1) and start processes (using RemoteProcess class) etc. But I can't find a way to delete a file from the device. The [msdn site](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384093%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) doesn't mention it, and googling about it has proven surprisingly difficult.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Is it not feasible to create a process that deletes files for you?

Comment: @yms well I could do that; in fact I have thought about it, but I just figured that there has to be a starightforward way of doing this... Thank you for your comment, if there is no better way then thats what I will do!

Comment: If the device is connected to your PC, you can use RAPI class to move /delete files

Comment: @R Quijano that looks like what I'm looking for. Can you provide a link? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can download it from

[RAPI OpenNetCF](http://rapi.codeplex.com/)

It has some examples